# Why is my cmake file not working while usual g++ code works perfectly

Tags: cmake

I am using tesseract-ocr and leptonica library in my small project.

My "CMakeLists.txt" file looks like following: (I have necessary header files in 'include' folder)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
project(OCR)
include_directories(include)
find_library(LEPT liblept)        
find_library(TESS libtesseract)    
set(LIBS ${LEPT} ${TESS})
add_executable(getText ocr.cpp)
target_link_libraries(getText ${LIBS})
```

But when I run this and then run make, my program does not get compiled

However, when I do this, it gets perfectly compiled

```
$ g++ ocr.cpp -o getText -I/usr/include/leptonica 
-I/usr/local/include/tesseract   -llept -ltesseract
```

But I need to make first approach succesful. Please help.

I have

```
#include "basapi.h"
#include "allheaders.h"
```

,by the way, in my code.

This is fine:

```
$ cmake .
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/utkrist/OCR
```

But this is not (gives some leptonica and tesseract-ocr related errors)

```
$ make 

    Linking CXX executable getText
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(imagefind.o): In function `tesseract::ImageFind::FindImages(Pix*)':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/textord/imagefind.cpp:78: undefined reference to `pixGenHalftoneMask'
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(tabfind.o): In function `tesseract::TabFind::Deskew(tesseract::TabVector_LIST*, BLOBNBOX_LIST*, TO_BLOCK*, FCOORD*, FCOORD*)':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/textord/tabfind.cpp:1286: undefined reference to `pixRotate'
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(svutil.o): In function `SVSemaphore':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/viewer/svutil.cpp:129: undefined reference to `sem_init'
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(svutil.o): In function `SVSemaphore::Signal()':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/viewer/svutil.cpp:137: undefined reference to `sem_post'
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(svutil.o): In function `SVSemaphore::Wait()':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/viewer/svutil.cpp:145: undefined reference to `sem_wait'
/usr/local/lib/libtesseract.a(svutil.o): In function `SVSync::StartThread(void* (*)(void*), void*)':
/home/utkrist/Downloads/tesseract-ocr/viewer/svutil.cpp:188: undefined reference to `pthread_create'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteToTiffStream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:646: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:647: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:648: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:650: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:651: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o):/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:652: more undefined references to `TIFFSetField' follow
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteToTiffStream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:723: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:732: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:742: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:688: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:689: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:690: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:691: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:695: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o):/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:696: more undefined references to `TIFFSetField' follow
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteToTiffStream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:763: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `writeCustomTiffTags':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:838: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteToTiffStream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:658: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:750: undefined reference to `TIFFWriteScanline'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:703: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:713: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:705: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:707: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:709: undefined reference to `TIFFSetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o):/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:666: more undefined references to `TIFFSetField' follow
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `getTiffStreamResolution':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1188: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1189: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1190: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `tiffReadHeaderTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1429: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1431: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1433: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1435: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1446: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1451: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixReadFromTiffStream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:287: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:288: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:299: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:300: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:301: undefined reference to `TIFFScanlineSize'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:334: undefined reference to `TIFFReadRGBAImageOriented'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:362: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:366: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:399: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:315: undefined reference to `TIFFReadScanline'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:382: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `openTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1721: undefined reference to `TIFFOpen'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `fopenTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1689: undefined reference to `TIFFFdOpen'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `fopenTiffMemstream':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1983: undefined reference to `TIFFClientOpen'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixReadStreamTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:231: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:237: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:241: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:226: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteTiffCustom':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:516: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteStreamTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:576: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:572: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `fprintTiffInfo':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1078: undefined reference to `TIFFPrintDirectory'  
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1079: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `tiffGetCount':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1114: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1118: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `getTiffResolution':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1155: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `freadHeaderTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1320: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1326: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `readHeaderMemTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1382: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1383: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1390: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `findTiffCompression':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1492: undefined reference to `TIFFGetFieldDefaulted'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1494: undefined reference to `TIFFCleanup'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `extractG4DataFromFile':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1599: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1602: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1606: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1607: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1608: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1611: undefined reference to `TIFFGetField'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:1613: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixReadMemTiff':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:2035: undefined reference to `TIFFReadDirectory'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:2042: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:2029: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(tiffio.o): In function `pixWriteMemTiffCustom':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/tiffio.c:2125: undefined reference to `TIFFClose'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(jpegio.o): In function `jpeg_error_do_not_exit':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:1118: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(jpegio.o): In function `pixReadStreamJpeg':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:259: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:262: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:265: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_marker_processor'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:266: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:267: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:272: undefined reference to `jpeg_calc_output_dimensions'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:310: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:374: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:399: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_decompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:400: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:336: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_scanlines'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:315: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_decompress'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(jpegio.o): In function `freadHeaderJpeg':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:491: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:493: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:494: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:495: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:496: undefined reference to `jpeg_calc_output_dimensions'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:507: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(jpegio.o): In function `fgetJpegResolution':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:545: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:547: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateDecompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:548: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_src'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:549: undefined reference to `jpeg_read_header'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:562: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_decompress'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(jpegio.o): In function `pixWriteStreamJpeg':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:699: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:702: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:703: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:717: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_defaults'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:732: undefined reference to `jpeg_set_quality'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:754: undefined reference to `jpeg_start_compress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:757: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_marker'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:797: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:800: undefined reference to `jpeg_finish_compress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:809: undefined reference to `jpeg_destroy_compress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:784: undefined reference to `jpeg_write_scanlines'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:734: undefined reference to `jpeg_simple_progression'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:699: undefined reference to `jpeg_std_error'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:702: undefined reference to `jpeg_CreateCompress'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/jpegio.c:703: undefined reference to `jpeg_stdio_dest'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(pngio.o): In function `pixReadStreamPng':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:182: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:186: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:191: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:202: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:218: undefined reference to `png_read_png'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:220: undefined reference to `png_get_rows'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:221: undefined reference to `png_get_image_width'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:222: undefined reference to `png_get_image_height'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:223: undefined reference to `png_get_bit_depth'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:224: undefined reference to `png_get_rowbytes'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:225: undefined reference to `png_get_color_type'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:226: undefined reference to `png_get_channels'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:336: undefined reference to `png_get_x_pixels_per_meter'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:337: undefined reference to `png_get_y_pixels_per_meter'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:342: undefined reference to `png_get_text'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:346: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:198: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:241: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:248: undefined reference to `png_get_PLTE'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:187: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:192: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:261: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(pngio.o): In function `fgetPngResolution':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:534: undefined reference to `png_create_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:537: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:551: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:552: undefined reference to `png_read_png'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:554: undefined reference to `png_get_x_pixels_per_meter'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:555: undefined reference to `png_get_y_pixels_per_meter'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:559: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:545: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:538: undefined reference to `png_destroy_read_struct'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(pngio.o): In function `pixWriteStreamPng':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:701: undefined reference to `png_create_write_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:705: undefined reference to `png_create_info_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:716: undefined reference to `png_init_io'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:721: undefined reference to `png_set_compression_level'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:754: undefined reference to `png_set_IHDR'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:764: undefined reference to `png_set_pHYs'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:804: undefined reference to `png_set_text'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:808: undefined reference to `png_write_info'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:840: undefined reference to `png_set_rows'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:843: undefined reference to `png_write_image'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:844: undefined reference to `png_write_end'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:886: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:712: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:781: undefined reference to `png_set_PLTE'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:791: undefined reference to `png_set_gAMA'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:860: undefined reference to `png_write_rows'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:882: undefined reference to `png_write_end'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:706: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:877: undefined reference to `png_write_rows'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/pngio.c:829: undefined reference to `png_destroy_write_struct'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(zlibmem.o): In function `zlibCompress':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:121: undefined reference to `deflateInit_'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:132: undefined reference to `deflate'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:144: undefined reference to `deflateEnd'
/usr/local/lib/liblept.a(zlibmem.o): In function `zlibUncompress':
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:201: undefined reference to `inflateInit_'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:212: undefined reference to `inflate'
/home/utkrist/leptonica-1.69/src/zlibmem.c:224: undefined reference to `inflateEnd'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [getText] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/getText.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the output that you get from running `cmake` and then the resulting `make`?

Comment: @Xymostech: I have posed the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced such problems several times, and what I do is to instruct CMake to generate a UNIX Makefile, and then look at what g++ command the Makefile is executing.

I know its not a great answer, but maybe It'll help.

Comment: I did this and the issue is now resolved
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)
    project(OCR)
    include_directories("${OCR_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
    add_executable(getText ocr.cpp)
    target_link_libraries(getText lept tesseract)